# get STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL when working with google play apk expansion file solution

Tags: android

we are trying to use google play's apk expansion file since our package is too big. After following the instruction in http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html and follow some posts in stackoverflow. we managed to have our code running.

But unfortunately, we are keep getting STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL. is there anything wrong? should we set anything before we start?

we have already put the apk and expansion file through the developer console.

any suggestion? thanks a lot.

[UPDATE]
I found the reason is because I haven't added the google account to test account, and not working with the apk signed with the same keystore as I uploaded to publish account. But after I succeeded once, it is ok to work with the apk signed by default debug keystore in eclipse. Besides, I forgot to click the Activate link to make my draft become active.